# Using Array.map to seach in array of dictionaries

Tags: arrays, swift

I'm trying to search for item inside of array of dictionaries and just return the match if there is any. Here is my code:

```
    let book = self.listOfBooks.map({ (Books) -> String in
        var bookName = String()
        if searchText == Books?. name{
           airportName = (Books?.author)!
            return airportName
        }
        return // Error: Non-void function should return a value
    })
```

But my problem is the .map is expecting return for each item in the array of self.listOfBooks. My question to you guys is how can just return the dictionary with only the matching the if ?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is `flatMap` not `map`.

```
let book = self.listOfBooks.flatMap({ (Books) -> String? in
    var bookName = String()
    if searchText == Books?.name{
        airportName = Books?.author
        return airportName
    }
    return nil
})
```

Shorter version

```
let airportNames = self.listOfBooks.flatMap { ($0?.name == searchText) ? $0?.author : nil }
```

**Edit:** If you want whole object not only `author` then you need to use `filter` for that.

```
let airportNames = self.listOfBooks.filter { $0?.name == searchText }
```

Comment: In the first example is complaining on this line return nil. Nil is incompatible with return type string. The second example works great but my question to you is if I want to return the whole dictionary and not only the string Books?.author. How can do that?

Comment: @user2924482 Check the edited answer to get whole object not only `author`